# Issue while creating an event subscription for outlook calendar

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to subscribe to Outlook Calendar notifications and I'm facing an issue. I tried to check if I have missed any scopes for my Calendar project in `portal.azure.com` and didn't find anything missing.

I am getting below error:

```
"error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Access to OData is disabled.]",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "0fcd3589-36d8-4acb-8d9a-408a7b75ee82",
      "date": "2019-05-19T12:00:22"
    }
  }
}
```

API used: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions`

Requesting for below stuff:

```
"changeType", "created,updated,deleted"
"resource", "/me/events"
```

What exactly does "Access to OData is disabled" mean?

Comment: Have you disabled [Integrated Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/misc/integrated-apps?WT.mc_id=365AdminCSH&view=o365-worldwide)?

Comment: I have not explicitly disabled anything related to Integrated Apps. Is there any default setting for that ? I have created app registration and this issue is being faced by a user trying to authorize his account belonging to a different organization. I have requested for minimal scopes i.e openid+email+Calendars.Read+offline_access. Does this happen if there is some setting like that from that organization ?

Comment: I am also seeing this error in few cases:

`"error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access to OData is disabled.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "06b35eb9-ffa3-4497-a1bc-5dc835697810",
      "date": "2019-05-17T20:05:33"
    }
  }
}`

code is different here from what I posted.

Comment: This isn't a setting you would change in _your_ tenant, it is one that is set in the tenant the authenticating user is calling into. Graph only talks to the current user's tenant, it doesn't matter if you registered it in a different tenant or not.

Comment: Ok! So, if the tenant user is authenticating from has disabled Integrated apps, we wont be able to make calls using their accesstoken ?

Comment: User has authorized his calendar and I am able to get the refreshToken. Further calls are made using his refreshToken which are having (OData access denied) issues. Please help me with some workaround or some resolution that I can approach on? This has been a blocker for us quite sometime. Thank you.

Comment: If they're able to consent, then I'm pretty sure integration apps isn't it. I don't believe it would allow you to get a token at all. Can you edit your question and include one of the tokens you're getting? It will help narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193655/discussion-between-mrbones-and-marc-lafleur).

Comment: Did you able to resolve it?